# How to add expiry date condition to login function in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In laravel 5.2, i want to add the condition so that only users where their expiry date is greater than today's date to login.

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{

return ['email' => $request->{$this->loginUsername()}, 'password' => $request->password];

}
```

The code does not accept adding:
    'expires' => gte(Carbon::now())

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, even in Laravel 5.5. Taking a look at the `retrieveByCredentials` method in `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` which is used to get the user from the database, you can see that the query passes simple key/value combinations to the `where` method on the `$query` object, which equate to `where key = value`. This is from 5.5:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    if (empty($credentials) ||
       (count($credentials) === 1 &&
        array_key_exists('password', $credentials))) {
        return;
    }

    // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
    // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
    // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```

To achieve what you are after I would recommend doing this check *after* the user has logged in, in your controller for instance:

```
// Imagine this is the controller method where you're dealing with user logins
public function login(array $credentials)
{
    if (! auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        // Handle what happens if the users credentials are incorrect.
    }

    $user = auth()->user();

    if (Carbon::now()->gte($user->expires)) {
        // User's account has expired, lets log them out.
        auth()->logout();

        // Return a redirect with a message or something...
    }

    // Handle a successful login.
}
```

I'm not sure if the `auth()` helper is available in 5.2, but you should be able to use the `Auth` facade to do the same thing, e.g. `Auth::attempt(...)`.